# expand div on click Polymer js without jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

I'm using Polymer but I'm having some trouble with events and the such. I want to create an expanding search bar, similar to

[image]

My current code looks something like the following:

**Code:**

```js
// This is where things are a little unclear for me. So far, I have tried the following:
expand: function() {
  var divToStretch = this.$.stretchMe;
  if ( /*search bar is open*/ ) {
    //remove "stretched" css from "stretch" div
  } else {
    //add "stretched" css to "stretch" div
  }
}
```

```css
div.stretch {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: width 1s;
}

.stretched {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="stretch" id="stretchMe">
  <iron-icon class="search" icon="search" on-click="expand"></iron-icon>
</div>
```

Comment: Would this help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest a **pure CSS alternative**? You can make your search bar receive focus, by adding `tabIndex="0"`. This way you can provide a style for `div.stretch:focus`, allowing you to dynamically change its size when the user clicks or focuses on the element and making it small again when the user focuses on something else.

It's really simple, elegant, does not need a lot of code and does what you need. Give it a try!

```css
div.stretch {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: width 1s;
}

div.stretch:focus {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="stretch" id="stretchMe" tabIndex="0">
  <iron-icon class="search" icon="search" on-click="expand"></iron-icon>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can make it do the same thing on `:hover`, if that's what you are after, simply by changing the selector. Or combine both, if you prefer. Below is a `:hover` example.

```css
div.stretch {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: width 1s;
}

div.stretch:hover {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="stretch" id="stretchMe">
  <iron-icon class="search" icon="search" on-click="expand"></iron-icon>
</div>
```

Comment: Still might be worth setting a class to keep it open when it contains text (provided that's what the OP wants) but I approve of using as little JS as possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `toggle` method of the `classList` for this:

```
expand : function() {
  this.$.stretchMe.classList.toggle('stretched');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The classic way would be as following:

```
if (/*search bar is open*/) {
    divToStretch.style.width = "auto";
 } else {
    divToStretch.style.width = "500px";
 }
```

But I highly recommend using   `this.$.stretchMe.classList.toggle('stretched');`

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)